# MYSQL Getting amounts summed twice when using JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following tables:

1. Bookings [id, clientId, clientBookingNumber, sellPrice]
2. BookingsPayments [bookingId, amount, mxnAmount]
3. BookingsCollections [id, clientId, bookingRangeStart, bookingRangeEnd, amount, mxnAmount]

I need to get booking sellPrice, booking total cost in MXN, COUNT how many payments each booking has, COUNT how many of those payments have an mxnAmount, booking total collected in MXN, COUNT how many collections each booking has and COUNT how many of those collections have an mxnAmount. Note that the way to link BookingsCollections with Bookings is using clientBookingNumber and that number should be between bookingRangeStart and bookingRangeEnd. Also note i'll give a specific clientId and bookingsRange.

I tried:

```
SELECT 
    b.sellPrice,
    SUM(bP.mxnAmount) AS mxnCost, COUNT(bP.id) AS qty, COUNT(bP.mxnAmount) AS mxnQty,
    SUM(c.mxnAmount) AS mxnColl, COUNT(c.id) AS collQty, COUNT(c.mxnAmount) AS collMxnQty 
FROM bookings b
JOIN bookingPayments bP ON b.id = bP.bookingId
JOIN collections c ON b.clientId = c.clientId AND b.clientBookingNumber BETWEEN c.bookingRangeStart AND c.bookingRangeEnd
WHERE ((b.clientId = 10) AND (b.clientBookingNumber >= 1) AND (b.clientBookingNumber <= 3))
GROUP BY b.id 
ORDER BY b.id
```

But i get the SUM amounts wrong, if only do one SUM/GROUP BY it works fine:

```
SELECT 
        b.sellPrice,
        SUM(bP.mxnAmount) AS mxnCost, COUNT(bP.id) AS qty, COUNT(bP.mxnAmount) AS mxnQty, 
FROM bookings b
JOIN bookingPayments bP ON b.id = bP.bookingId
WHERE ((b.clientId = 10) AND (b.clientBookingNumber >= 1) AND (b.clientBookingNumber <= 3))
GROUP BY b.id 
ORDER BY b.id
```

Any Leads?

Comment: please see [mre] and add some data. As you noticed you can't add 1:n Relationships, you have to sum it up before you join them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pre-aggregate before joining, otherwise rows are "multiplied":

```
SELECT b.id, bp.*, c.*
FROM bookings b
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT bookingId, SUM(mxnAmount) AS mxnCost, COUNT(id) AS qty, COUNT(mxnAmount) AS mxnQty
    FROM bookingPayments
    GROUP BY bookingId
) bp ON bp.bookingId = b.id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT clientId, bookingRangeStart, bookingRangeEnd, SUM(mxnAmount) AS mxnColl, COUNT(id) AS collQty, COUNT(mxnAmount) AS collMxnQty 
    FROM collections
    GROUP BY clientId, bookingRangeStart, bookingRangeEnd
) c ON c.clientId = b.clientId 
    AND b.clientBookingNumber BETWEEN c.bookingRangeStart AND c.bookingRangeEnd
ORDER BY b.id
```

Comment: thanks! didnt know i had to aggregate first. Im just wondering how can i make the results to be grouped by b.id, as of now if i have all collections with same range e.g. 1-2 they get grouped, but if i have one 1-2 and another one 1-1 i get two separated rows with same data, i would want it to give me for each booking its ID, MXNCOST, QTY, MXNQTY, MXNCOLL, COLLQTY and COLLMXNQTY, im passing the range so it should somehow get all booking numbers within the range and get the data separately, not sure if possible, been trying to do it without success